# Как поместить 2 и более слова в один arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
cmd.on(/^(?:\/|\+|\!)(?:pm|от|ans|rr)\s([^]+)\s([^]+)/i, 'Ответ на репорт', 0, (message, args)  => {
if(message.user == 176778059,152408885){
vk.api.call("messages.send", {
 chat_id: message.args[1],
 message: message.args[2]
});
```

При отправке 1 слова все работает, но если вписать 2 и более то ничего не срабатывает. Как исправить?

Answer (score 3):

Решил проблему. Нужно в первых скобках убрать "+".

Comment: Классно, за 3 минуты...Хорошая скорость решения.